# How to configure paragraph to automatically have a indentation of 1.27 cm?

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS word, after creating a new heading, I have to setting the paragraph indentation manually every time.  How do I configure the document to always indent?

I also find that after creating the heading, when I press "Enter", the heading format is getting carried over to the next line as well.  Probably, this is clearing the previous formatting information for Normal style.

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand right that you want to have the paragraph indentation of 1.27 cm for the first line after your header?

Then you have to do the following:

1. Define new Normal-based style in your document.
2. For this style define the first line option to have 1.27 cm indentation and the style of the following paragraph set to "Normal".
3. Modify your headings to have your newly-created style as the style of the next paragraph.

So you reach that after every heading the very first paragraph has a first line indentatino.

Here is the picture how you set your new style:

[image: Setting new normal-based style with the first line indentation]